# How to set maximum amount of columns in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to split screen into two equal parts, so I need to set maximum amount of available columns for the layout. How to do it? `stretchColumns` is not an option since it also streches buttons.

Example:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You can try `layout_weight` within `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="0"
 />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_column="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```